# The bottom navbar is not showing icon in react_native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

[image: Actually all packages install but it not showing icon in bottom navbar]

In my code install all packages and  trying different ways to show icon  bottom navbar but not showing. Anyone can give me  any suggestion that showing in my icon in bottom navbar and icons from Ant design or Entypo,  the font files are properly installed  in my  project

Comment: Can you change the color and the size of the icon with custom ones? <Entypo name="documents" size={25} color={'red'} /> and share the result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the below line in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```js
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
```